Windows SDK: Mnemonic not workling
This is a small program
#include <windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
  MSG  msg ;    
  WNDCLASS wc = {0};
  wc.style          = CS_GLOBALCLASS;
  wc.lpszClassName = TEXT( "Buttons" );
  wc.hInstance     = hInstance ;
  wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
  wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
  wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
  RegisterClass(&wc);

  wc.style          = CS_GLOBALCLASS;
  wc.lpszClassName = TEXT( "Frame" );
  wc.hInstance     = hInstance ;
  wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
  wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
  wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
  RegisterClass(&wc);

  HWND hwnd = CreateWindow( wc.lpszClassName, TEXT("Buttons"),
                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                150, 150, 230, 150, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);  
  while( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    if( !IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &msg) )
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
  }
  return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
  switch(msg)  
  {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HWND frame = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("Frame"), TEXT("&Beep"),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                     0, 0, 230, 130,        
                     hwnd, 0, NULL, NULL);    
        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("&Beep"),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
                     20, 50, 80, 25,        
                     frame, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);    
        CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("&Quit"),    
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP ,
                     120, 50, 80, 25,        
                     frame, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL);    
        break;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
       if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) {
           Beep(400, 50);
       }

       if (LOWORD(wParam) == 2) {
              PostQuitMessage(0);
       }

       break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
       PostQuitMessage(0);
       break;
      }
  }
  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

The access keys are not working. That meeans instead of sending the corresponding WM_COMMAND messages a warning bell sounds.
The mcrosoft SDK documentation says that this should work but it doesn't. With or without the call of IsDialogMessage makes no difference. I would expect that hitting Alt+Q on the keyboard would terminate the application.
The problem seems to be the frame window. Without the frame when creating the buttons as a child of the overapped window after setting the focus to one of the buttons everthing works as expected.


The frame window should have the WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT extended style set.
It should be if (!IsDialogMessage(...
Assigning the same WndProc to two different classes does not make sense.



Thanks, helped here in this example.
That was a typo, I will fix it here
That was just for demonstration, That is not "real" code.

My original problem still exists,  I have to try to create another example.
Nevertheless, thanks a lot,

A billion thanks. WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT  solved my problem. With Windows NT and 32-Bit Code EVERYTHING worked as expected. Windows 10 does not transfer the input focus correctly. I have to find out the reason.
Again: Many, Many thanks.

If it solved the problem then you should mark it as the answer...
